# Cómo sumar los precios en etiquetas span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poder sumar los precios de las etiquetas span que se encuentra dentro del div con la id 'precios' ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? o que otra forma existe? no descartando el div.

```
<div id='precios'>
<span>$25USD</span>
<span>$15USD</span>
<span>$22USD</span>
<span>$13USD</span>
<!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean bien aceptadas por la comunidad, ya que te falta el código de lo que haz intentado para llegar a tu objetivo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente

```js
//Función que sumará los valores contenidos dentro de tus spans
function sumar() {
  //Capturas todos los elementos spans que están dentro del div con id 'precios'
  var preciosSpan = document.querySelectorAll('#precios span');
  //Obtienes el span donde mostraras el resultado de la suma
  var resultadoSpan = document.querySelector('#resultado');
  //Inicializas la variable que contendrá el resultado de la suma
  var total = 0;
  //Recorres todos los spans dentro del div 'precios'
  preciosSpan.forEach(function(span) {
      //Sumas a total el valor que venia con el más el valor contenido dentro 
      //de cada spans removiendo el caracter '$' y las letras de la moneda 'USD' 
    total += parseFloat(span.innerHTML.replace('$','').replace('USD',''));
  });
                   
  //Asignas al texto contenido dentro del span del resultado de la suma el valor calculado
  resultado.innerHTML = '$'+total+'USD';
}
```

```html
<div id='precios'>
 <span>$25USD</span><br />
 <span>$15USD</span><br />
 <span>$22USD</span><br />
 <span>$13USD</span><br />
</div>
<br /><hr />

<!-- Ubicación donde se mostrará el resultado de la suma -->
<b>Resultado:</b> <span id="resultado"></span><br /><br />

 <!-- Boton para lanzar la ejecución de la sumatoria -->
<button id="sumar" onClick="sumar()">Sumar</button>
```

Comment: y cómo se separa con puntos? porque si sumo 1.250.456 + 878.556 el resultado queda muy raro

Comment: Tienes que ver como vas a poner el separador de miles y como el de decimales, edita tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mas. No es igual la manera de procesarlo si tu numero es 1.023.435,23 o si es 1,023,435.23

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar de esta forma:

```js
// obtenemos todos los spans
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("#precios > span");
let total = 0;

document.getElementById('calcular').addEventListener('click', function () {
// iteramos sobre cada elemento
spans.forEach(function(element) {
  let value = element.innerHTML;  
  // eliminamos todo lo que no sea numero
  value = parseFloat(value.replace(/(?!-)[^0-9.]/g,''))
  total += value
})

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = `$${total}USD`
});
```

```html
<div id='total'>$0USD</div>
<div id='precios'>
  <span>$25.5USD</span>
  <span>$15.95USD</span>
  <span>$22USD</span>
  <span>$13USD</span>
</div>

<button id='calcular'>Calcular</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**puedes hacerlo asi:**

```js
// contendra nuestros numeros
let nums=[];
let num2=[];
// seleccioanmos los div span y hacemos
// un loop por cada elemento 
document.querySelectorAll("div span").forEach((v,k) =>{
   ///           opcion 1         \\\\ 
   // obtenemos el texto de los span
   // y obtenemos los numeros atravez de una expresion regular
   // y agregamos el resultado a arreglo nums
   nums.push( parseFloat(v.textContent.replace(/\D+/g,'') ) )
   ///           opcion2           \\\\    
   // obtenemos el texto de los span
   // con slice obtenemos a partir
   // del caracter 1 hasta el -3
   num2.push(v.textContent.slice(1,-3) );
});

// sumamos todos los numeros del arreglo nums con la funcion reduce
let suma = nums.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
let suma2 = nums.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
console.log(suma)
console.log(suma2)
```

```html
<div id='precios'>
<span>$25USD</span>
<span>$15USD</span>
<span>$22USD</span>
<span>$13USD</span>
<!-- etc -->
</div>
```